# Releasing all locked threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, synchronization

I want to release all locked threads after one of them passes and complete the some task. Let me post some sample code about what I want to do. The important thing is they must pass all together after first thread completed his job. They(rest 99 threads) must be like that they have never locked not pass one by one.

```
         Monitor.Enter(_lock);//imagine 100x threads hit this lock at same time.  
        //1 thread pass there
        if (data == null)
        {
            data = GetData();
        }

        Monitor.Exit(_locker);//one more thread allow after this code.And they all come one by one in order.In these point I want to release them all together.
```

I have tried lots of class about threading like Monitor, Mutex, Semaphore, ReadWriteLock, ManaualResetEvent etc. but I didn't manage to do this, they all come one by one. Have you ever done this? Or Have you got ant idea about that? I don't wanna spent more time on it.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most efficient way but it will work:

```
static SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
static CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
static void CriticalSection()
{
    if(!cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        try
        {
            semaphore.Wait(cts.Token);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ) { }
    }
    /*
    Critical section here
    */
    if(!cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
        cts.Cancel();
}
```

the SemaphoreSlim will only let 1 thread run the "critical section". After the first thread is over with the section it will cancel the token. This will lead into an OperationCanceledException as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321647(v=vs.110).aspx).  All the threads that were waiting will throw the exception that will be catched in the "try catch statement" and then execute the critical section. The first "if statement" is to check the state of the token to avoid the wait and throw pattern if it has been cancelled in the past.

The performance hit will be on the first time you have your threads "released" from the wait since they will all throw an exception. Later on, the only impact is going to be around the cancellation token check and the general maintainability of your code.

Comment: This code has every caller run the critical section once the CTS has been cancelled.

Comment: @Servy isn't that exactly what the OP asked for ?

Comment: The value needs to be constructed *exactly once*.

Comment: @Servy The null check will return true since it is null for the first thread. All the other threads will then run after the token gets cancelled and the null check ill always return false so the object will only be "constructed" once.  the OP seemed to ask us to overlook what was done in the critical section and it is what this solution is about.  This mechanism will allow 1 thread to run in the critical section and then all the others will run at the same time when the first is done.

Comment: @Daneau It didnt work for me but I achive what I want to do without cts I post it as new answer bottom.ty.

Comment: @Math1 I would be curious to see why this implementation didn't work. Do you have a code sample so I can see what you tried ?  At this point it is also to help the community that might have a similar issue. the solution that worked for you isn't exactly appropriate since it is only working with a very low number of threads and it can throw a SemaphoreFullException after running for a while.

Comment: @deneau how you ever tried this code? all tread hit wait and not resume after cancel like deadlock.

Comment: @deneau but if you say this code is work. I will try again.

Comment: @Math1 Yes this code work. Here is a fully operational samble: https://pastebin.com/7j5TuNJC. 
Just remember that your computer can't run 1000 thread at the exact same time. The ThreadPool limits the number of concurrent threads that can be running at once.

Answer (score -2):

```
    static SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(LoadDataPart);
            t.Name = (i + 1).ToString();
            t.Start();
        }

        Console.Read();
    }

    static void LoadDataPart()
    {


        Console.WriteLine("Before Wait {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
        semaphore.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("After Wait {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Console.WriteLine("Done {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.Name);

        semaphore.Release(10);//this line must be changed,its allow too much thread coz its called 10 times!

    }
```

I can manage what I want to do like this. In this code sample 10 threads hit wait. 9 of them waited other one keep going. When 1 thread done his job other 9 goes together not one by one. To check that I put thread sleep and all threads complated in 6 sec not in 30 secs. Now I can customize my code.

Comment: There is a few flaw with this approach. Unless you know the exact number of thread to be expected, the semaphore.Release(x) wont allow the "must pass all together " part of your question. In this case it is working because your thread number is low and you release exactly the same number as your thread count and because the "criticalsection" is not taking that long. You will also increase the semaphore count often as pointed out in the sample.

Comment: @Daneau Yes I noticed that this problem. Maybe I can use that somehow but Its not looks like exact solution. I think there is no healty way to do that.